# Making the ask box font smaller on a Tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

How would I go about setting a smaller font size on the ask box on a Tumblr? I don't know where on my current theme I have to adjust or edit for this section to have a font size smaller than the rest of the page.

Comment: I suggest providing a little bit more info here!

Answer (score 1):

This is because this is not possible to do with CSS, these are two different pages, you would have to dynamically place JavaScript to pull in the CSS into the iFrame html content.

The most you can do is play with the iFrame itself

```
iframe#ask_form
```